# How to get user text input and render it to an element on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, input

So I'm testing out this thing where I can write something in a text input, and then have that render to the page. I have a text input with the id `user-text` and a submit input with the id `apply-button`, and a target `<p>` tag where the entry should go. Essentially, you type in the entry into the text input and click the button, and it should render to the target. But that's not working for me. Here's my code.

```js
let userInput = document.querySelector('#user-text');
const applyButton = document.querySelector('#apply-button');
let userTarget = document.querySelector('#user-target');

applyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        userTarget.textContent = userInput.nodeValue;                     
});
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <p><input type='text' id='user-text' placeholder="Type your day here."name='blogtext'><input type='submit' id='apply-button'value='Click to Apply'>


    </div>
    <div id='target'>
        <p id='user-target'></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `userInput.value` to get value from input field. Also your first `<p>` tag is not closed.

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p><input type='text' id='user-text' placeholder="Type your day here."name='blogtext'><input type='submit' id='apply-button'value='Click to Apply'>
            
           
        </div>
        <div id='target'>
            <p id='user-target'></p>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        let userInput = document.querySelector('#user-text');
        const applyButton = document.querySelector('#apply-button');
        let userTarget = document.querySelector('#user-target');
        
        applyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                userTarget.textContent = userInput.value;                     
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I would also like to know how to save the input, as using this code after I refresh my page the user input is gone.

Answer (score 0):

when you performing click on function, "nodeValue" is coming null that why you trying to set value to html its not coming on UI.

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p><input type='text' id='user-text' placeholder="Type your day here."name='blogtext'><input type='submit' id='apply-button'value='Click to Apply'>


        </div>
        <div id='target'>
            <p id='user-target'></p>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    console.log('called');
        let userInput = document.querySelector('#user-text');
        const applyButton = document.querySelector('#apply-button');
        let userTarget = document.querySelector('#user-target');

        applyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                userTarget.textContent = userInput.value;                     
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let userInput = document.querySelector('#user-text');
const applyButton = document.querySelector('#apply-button');
let userTarget = document.querySelector('#user-target');

applyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        userTarget.innerHTML = userInput.value;                     
});
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <p><input type='text' id='user-text' placeholder="Type your day here."name='blogtext'><input type='submit' id='apply-button'value='Click to Apply'>


    </div>
    <div id='target'>
        <p id='user-target'></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

get [textarea value](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_value.asp) and put it in your element using [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp).